# Hacer un registro único en base de datos usando while en Python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando crear un valor único en la base de datos con un valor random, empezando por el número del año. Es decir, pueden quedar valores como los siguientes:

```
16EP784
16TTU3I
1699UYT
```

La idea es generar un código único para cada cliente. La base de datos no lo  permitiría, pero eso sería como un mecanismo de seguridad a la programación realizada.

Se crea un nuevo registro y se crea con un código random. Luego, si el valor generado ya existe en la base de datos, la segunda instrucción crea otro.

Ejemplo con una lista:

```python
lista = [1,2,3]
if 2 in lista:
    #crea otro valor <---
```

La pregunta es cómo lo haría para que se asegure una y otra vez de que el valor generado no existe, ni el tercero, ni el cuarto...

No entiendo cómo se podría hacer eso con un `while`, que según entiendo bastaría para hacerlo.

Comment: `if 2 not in lista:` para verificar que no esté en la lista.

Comment: Hola @Rosendo. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Si estás buscando una respuesta para una lista, bien. Pero si estás buscando respuestas para ver valores duplicados en la base de datos, deberías [edit] la pregunta para mostrar cómo te estás conectando a la base, qué columna tiene el valor que debería ser único y por qué no podrías confiar en un valor autogenerado en la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que deseas se puede resumir en los siguientes pasos:

1. Generar un 'id' para un nuevo cliente
2. Si el 'id' generado ya existe, entonces generar otro 'id'
3. Repetir paso 2 hasta que se genere un 'id' que no exista
4. Agregar el 'id' a la lista de 'id's

Estoy en lo correcto ?

En python podemos "traducir" las instrucciones como sigue:

```
def generarNuevoId():
    """
    Funcion que genera un nuevo id de forma aleatoria
    """
    # instrucciones que generan el id

lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]    # lista de 'id's

nuevoid = generarNuevoId()

while nuevoid in lista:
    nuevoid = generarNuevoId()

lista.append(nuevoid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Por medio de un `While` como lo mencionaste , el `if` para validar si existe. el 20 sería el total de números generados requeridos

```
from random import randint

lista =[]
i=0
while i<20:
    val = randint(0,100)
    if val not in lista:
        print("No Existe")
        lista.append(val)
    i+=1

print(lista)
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/EJkz/2)

Aunque para lo que desea le convendría tener una función y que retorne el valor generado

```
from random import randint
def returnIdUnique(lista):

    while True:
        val = randint(0,100)
        if val not in lista:
            lista.append(val)
            return val

lista= [1,4,2]
print(returnIdUnique(lista))
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/EJlS/1)